# Powershell run a shell command with arguments from string

Tags: parameters, powershell-2.0

Powershell's command line handling is frustrating to say the least.

I am trying to generate a command like below and execute it from powershell

```
type ".\id_rsa.pub" | ".\plink.exe" -ssh user@example.com -pw usepass  "umask 077; test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys; exit; "
```

However I keep getting the pair of errors, depending on how I try to execute it (with Invoke-Expression or &).

```
ERROR: You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
ERROR: The term 'type ".\id_rsa.pub" | ".\plink.exe" -ssh user@example.com -pw usepass  "umask 077; test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys; exit; "' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I've googled extensively and looked at all the related stackoverflow questions and answers. I've tried changing the quotes around and commands but no luck so far.

This is the script. I am calling it quits for today. I have a batch file that's working, but it's parameter handling was terrible making it difficult for me to use it from external programs (like mremoteng). It depends on [plink.exe](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe) and create a dummy file `id_rsa.pub` in the same folder

```
<#
 .NAME
    ssh-copy-id.ps1
 .SYNOPSIS
    Copy public key to remote hosts
 .DESCRIPTION
    See Synopsis
 .SYNTAX
    Invoke directly from the powershell command line
 .EXAMPLES
    .\Scriptname -i idtest.pub user@example.com password
    .\Scriptname -i idtest.pub user@example.com password -Debug
    .\ScriptName user@example.com password
.NOTES
    AUTHOR: VijayS
    DATE:   2014-01-23
    COMMENT: 
    DEPENDENCIES: 
        plink.exe
        type
 .HELPURL
    http://stackoverflow.com
 .SEEALSO
 .REFERNCE
    http://www.christowles.com/2011/06/how-to-ssh-from-powershell-using.html
#>

Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$user_at_hostname,

    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    [String]$Password,

    [Parameter(HelpMessage="The public key file to copy")]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [Alias("i")]
    [String]$identity="id_rsa.pub",

    [switch]$ConnectOnceToAcceptHostKey=$false
    )

####################################
Function Get-SSHCommands {
 Param($Target,$Password, $CommandArray,
  $PlinkAndPath,
  $ConnectOnceToAcceptHostKey = $true)

 $plinkoptions = "-ssh $Target"
 if ($Password) { $plinkoptions += " -pw $Password " }

 #Build ssh Commands
 $CommandArray += "exit"
 $remoteCommand = ""
 $CommandArray | % {
  $remoteCommand += [string]::Format('{0}; ', $_)
 }

 #plist prompts to accept client host key. This section will
 #login and accept the host key then logout.
 if($ConnectOnceToAcceptHostKey)
 {
  $PlinkCommand  = [string]::Format("echo y | & '{0}' {1} exit",
   $PlinkAndPath, $plinkoptions )
  #Write-Host $PlinkCommand
  $msg = Invoke-Expression $PlinkCommand
 }

 #format plist command
 # $PlinkCommand = [string]::Format("'{0}' {1} '{2}'",
 #  $PlinkAndPath, $plinkoptions , $remoteCommand)
 $PlinkCommand = [string]::Format('"{0}" {1} "{2}"',
  $PlinkAndPath, $plinkoptions , $remoteCommand)

 #ready to run the following command
 #Write-Debug $PlinkCommand
 return $PlinkCommand
 #$msg = Invoke-Expression $PlinkCommand
 #$msg
}

##################
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" # "Continue" "SilentlyContinue" "Stop" "Inquire"
$DebugPreference = "Continue"
trap { #Stop on all errors
    Write-Error "ERROR: $_"
}

$PlinkAndPath = '.\plink.exe'

#from http://serverfault.com/questions/224810/is-there-an-equivalent-to-ssh-copy-id-for-windows
$Commands = @()
$Commands += "umask 077" #change permissions to be restrictive
$Commands += "test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh" #test and create .ssh director if it doesn't exist
$Commands += "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys" #append the public key to file

#Write-Debug $Password
#Write-Debug $identity

Try {
    $tmp = Get-ItemProperty -Path $identity
    $tmp = Get-ItemProperty -Path $PlinkAndPath

    $cmd = Get-SSHCommands -Target $user_at_hostname `
     -Password $Password `
     -PlinkAndPath $PlinkAndPath `
     -CommandArray $Commands `
     -ConnectOnceToAcceptHostKey $ConnectOnceToAcceptHostKey

     # pipe the public key to the plink session to get it appended in the right place
     $cmd = "type ""$identity"" | " + $cmd
     Write-Debug $cmd
     #Invoke-Expression $cmd
     & $cmd
}
Catch {
    Write-Error "$($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[--%](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) stops PowerShell from parsing the rest. That in combination with not putting plink.exe in quotes might do the trick.

```
type ".\id_rsa.pub" | .\plink.exe --% -ssh user@example.com -pw usepass "umask 077; test -d .ssh || mkdir .ssh; cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys; exit; "
```

**update**

--% only works in PowerShell 3 and higher. For lower versions you might try to escape all conflicting characters with ` (back tick). See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892%28v=wps.620%29.aspx).

Comment: Doesn't --% work only [with v3](https://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters.aspx?Redirected=true)? I am trying to keep the script compatible with v2.

Comment: Yes, v3 only. For lower version you need to use `